# div Width is being ignored

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a series of buttons inside some divs programmatically.

Here is the [code](http://jsbin.com/bememidira/1/edit?html,css,js,output):

Why is the `width: 110px` being ignored?

Comment: Please post your html and possibly a live example of the problem

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the images. (Edited)

Comment: You likely have another style that is overwriting the width for the div. This could be a more specific selector (like an ID selector), or is the same selector higher in the hierarchy, or an inline style. Can you post any other HTML or CSS you have?

Comment: My friend, we really need to see some code. Images of pages don't help. Maybe use codepen.io?? Or just insert some html here. The only reason a div would not take width is that it is displayed `inline`, or your selector isn't correct, or it's being overwritten by a more specific selector. We need html and css to see...

Comment: Sorry, I add more information.

Comment: Your JS files are local. You must add all the code related to a healthy solution. You can use http://jsbin.com etc.

Comment: Sorry again, jsbin added.

Comment: your css `button.l` should be `button.letter`

Comment: Thanks, I made the change.
The code seems good on a 1920 screen, but when I reduce the size appear the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button has a width of 110px but is placed in a div that only has a width of 8.3333%. This comes from the .s1 class. Removing the class shows each button with a 110px width as desired.

```
.row .col.s1 {
    /* width: 8.3333333333%; */
    margin-left: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey, The container It's not aligned to center, you know how to fix it?http://jsbin.com/gogofidola/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Add display: inline-block to div.row. Then if you need a background color add it to the container.

Answer (score 0):

The stylesheet included **materialize.min.css** has a class **.col.s1** 
that has a width of **8.3333...%**. You will need to override this in your css

```
div.col.x {
    width: 110px !important;
}
```

I usually don't like using !important unless necessary but without more of your code to look at, this could do it.