# Resize of div is being ignored

Tags: javascript, html, styles, width

I have a super-simple web page that loads data from a server into s as containers. The problem is that sometimes images are too tall, and overflow and cause layout problems. So, I was looking to resize the divs using:

```
target.style.height = height; // As short form of:
document.getElementById('someId').style.height=height;
```

But so far NOTHING I've tried has worked. Here's the html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#E3FBFF" text="#000000" onload="loadImages();">
      <script type = "text/javascript">
        function loadImages()
        {
          ...Function omitted for brevity...
          But it gets to this line:
          document.getElementById(d0).style.height = height+10;
        }
  </script>
    <div id=d0></div>
    <hr>
    <div id=d1></div>
    <hr>
    <div id=d2></div>
    <hr>
    <div id=d3></div>
    <hr>
    </body>
    </html>
```

That's it!

I have found various articles [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33080/setting-the-height-of-a-div-dynamically), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261126/div-width-is-being-ignored), but, they weren't helpful.

It occurs to me to mention that in my case I don't require the use of divs per se. I just need the images and related text to not overlap vertically (or horizontally). As it is, when the images load, it can be a real mess. ...How can I tell my divs to be full width with no overlay from the other divs? I tried using a class, using CSS, and more, all ignored.

I guess I was working under the improper assumption that divs, as block-oriented things, that even if you declare full width ("width=100%") can and will STILL overlap vertically depending on the contents placed in them.

Comment: what is 'height'? it seems you didnt declare it, also when setting height you should append 'px' or '%', just assigning a number wont work

Comment: I believe @ChrisLi is correct, I just wanted to add that this is because `style` refers to a CSS property which is why it requires the unit. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height and the first example you linked where they add `+ "px"` to the height value at the end.

Comment: @ChrisLi OK, then, how to I ad "px" after my integer?! With a +"px"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didnt show what you assigned to 'height', but from your code i assume its an interger.

```
document.getElementById(d0).style.height = height+10;
```

style takes a string (ie 10px), so assigning number to it won't work, try the following

```
document.getElementById(d0).style.height = height+10+'px';
```

javascript will convert it to string for you
more on integer to string here [What's the best way to convert a number to a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765398/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Add a unit to your `height` variable. As you are editing the CSS style of the element this is required. See: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

`document.getElementById('someId').style.height=height` becomes:
`document.getElementById('someId').style.height = height.toString() + 'px'`

Comment: try int.toString()